# How to pass a kerberos username to a flask app from apache

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache, ldap, kerberos

I'm doing some python work on a flask app that's sitting behind apache. Kerberos is used for authentication so that's relatively simple to set up - just a few apache directives. But there doesn't seem to be an easy way to authorise with apache so we're using LDAP in the python code to authenticate - also relatively simple to set up. The only problem that I'm having is getting the credentials from apache/Kerberos onto the python side of things. Is there any simple way to get this to work that works with python3? Note that the python-krbV module only seems to work with Python2 and there are no plans at the moment for that library to be ported over to Python3.